# AIX Missing Symbols ap_cleanup_scoreboard and ap_accept_lock_mech for Apache Process. However, the symbols do exist

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, aix, mod-wsgi

I am having a problem whereby apache is not able to find certain symbols referenced from a library (mod_wsgi) loaded within the apache process.

When i start the apache process, i get this error.

```
root [zibal]% ./usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl restart
httpd: Syntax error on line 53 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
Cannot load /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: 

rtld:0712-001 Symbol ap_cleanup_scoreboard was referenced from module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so(), but a runtime definition of the symbol was not found.

rtld: 0712-001 Symbol ap_accept_lock_mech was referenced from module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so(), but a runtime definition of the symbol was not found
```

I am pasting the output of nm command on the apache executable and those symbols seem to exist.

```
root [zibal]% nm ./usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd | grep  ap_accept_lock_mech
ap_accept_lock_mech  D   536880332
ap_accept_lock_mech  d   536900392           4
ap_accept_lock_mech:G879 -           0

root [zibal]% nm ./usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd | grep ap_cleanup_scoreboard
.ap_cleanup_scoreboard T   268613428         212
ap_cleanup_scoreboard D   536890068
ap_cleanup_scoreboard d   536890068          12
ap_cleanup_scoreboard d   536899972           4
ap_cleanup_scoreboard:F385 -        2976
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1 (Thanks to Jeff Trawick from Apache)

Extract the Source tar ball in a directory.....cd into that directory

Locate the file include/mpm_common.h

Change 
 extern apr_lockmech_e ap_accept_lock_mech;
to
 AP_DECLARE_DATA extern apr_lockmech_e ap_accept_lock_mech;

Locate the file include/scoreboard.h

Change
 apr_status_t ap_cleanup_scoreboard(void *d); 
to
 AP_DECLARE(apr_status_t) ap_cleanup_scoreboard(void *d);

And then issue the following commands
 ./configure
 make

After this step, there will be a httpd.exp file create in the server directory and a httpd file created in the present directory

remove httpd

edit server/httpd.exp and add one line for ap_accept_lock_mech

make
 make install (as root)

Then build mod_wsgi 3.3 from Source Tarball

## Solution 2 (Thanks to Graham Dumpleton)

Don't change anything in Apache Code.

Go into mod_wsgi.c source code and change:

```
   /*
    * Cleanup the Apache scoreboard to ensure that any
    * shared memory segments or memory mapped files not
    * available to code in daemon processes.
    */

   ap_cleanup_scoreboard(0);
```

to

## if 0

```
   /*
    * Cleanup the Apache scoreboard to ensure that any
    * shared memory segments or memory mapped files not
    * available to code in daemon processes.
    */

   ap_cleanup_scoreboard(0);
```

## endif

and then look for:

## if !defined(AP_ACCEPT_MUTEX_TYPE)

sconfig->lock_mechanism = ap_accept_lock_mech;

## else

sconfig->lock_mechanism = APR_LOCK_DEFAULT;

## endif

and change it to:

## define AP_ACCEPT_MUTEX_TYPE 1

## if !defined(AP_ACCEPT_MUTEX_TYPE)

sconfig->lock_mechanism = ap_accept_lock_mech;

## else

sconfig->lock_mechanism = APR_LOCK_DEFAULT;

## endif

Then build mod_wsgi